# Facing error while Creating Targeting Criteria using Twitter Ads API

Tags: api, twitter, ads

Create a targeting profile associated with the line item. If I post this in postman, I am getting the below error: Can anyone look into this and provide the solution, please.

Note*: I have changed the value “xxx” to mask the values.

POST https://ads-api.twitter.com/9/accounts/XXXXXXXX/targeting_criteria?line_item_id=XXXX&targeting_type=LOCATION&targeting_value=3b77caf94bfc81fe

````
“errors”: [
{
“code”: “MISSING_PARAMETER”,
“message”: ““operator_type” is a required parameter”,
“parameter”: “operator_type”
}
],
“request”: {
“params”: {
“line_item_id”: “xxx”,
“targeting_type”: “LOCATION”,
“targeting_value”: “xxxxx”,
“account_id”: “xxxx”
}
}
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The[documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/campaign-management/api-reference/targeting-criteria#post-accounts-account-id-targeting-criteria) states that `operator_type` is a required field. It should work passing in `EQ`

`POST https://ads-api.twitter.com/9/accounts/XXXXXXXX/targeting_criteria?line_item_id=XXXX&targeting_type=LOCATION&targeting_value=3b77caf94bfc81fe&operator_type=EQ`